# Extract table from string python

Tags: python, string, pandas, websocket

In Python
Websocket Feed me string like this:

```
'{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}'
```

I would like to convert this string to a table:

```
{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}
```

It seems like the only difference is the apostrophes at the beginning and the end. 
Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

def StringToJson(string):

    # [1:-1] Assuming you only want to remove the quotes at either end. Strip()           
    #because there might after all be some whitespace present.

    return json.loads(string.strip()[1:-1])


string = """'{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}'""" 

table = StringToJson(string)
```

If the solution above does not work it might simply just be the case that the quotes that you think are present are just part of the error messages that you get. You can try the following:

```
import json

parsedString  = json.loads(string) # Where string is the text you're trying to access the keys of.
```

Comment: It works! thanks! 
Additional question: how to convert the string directly to a dic?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a json object back.  You could use python's built in json converter to turn it into a python dict.

```
import json
t = json.loads('{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}')
```

`t` will now be the dictionary with those key/value pairs

See this page for more examples. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Wont work as there are quotes at both ends and json will throw the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

Comment: Oh, I see.  I didn't realize that was part of the string.  You could do '{"type":"done","sequence":49109868,"time":"2015-04-06T17:57:00.86877Z"}'[1,-1]

Comment: Looks like @user2973474 beat me to it